# django reusable redirect best practice

Tags: django, redirect

I've got many views that need the same functionality so I'm trying to move that logic into a separate function (not a view function). The function finds a value either in the GET or session and returns a model instance **OR** redirects to a new page (kind of like forcing a login). The problem is that you can't redirect from a called function (that I know of). How should I handle this scenario?

Here's my code:

```
# This is the called function
def getActiveShowOrRedirect(request):
    show_pk = request.GET.get('s', False)
    if not show_pk:
        show_pk = request.session.get('show_pk', False)
        if not show_pk:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/setup/')
    active_show = Show.objects.get(pk=show_pk)
    return active_show

def overview(request):
    active_show = getActiveShowOrRedirect(request)

    scenes = Scene.objects.filter(show=active_show)
    scenes = sorted(scenes, key=lambda s: s.name) 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SceneForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            desc = form.cleaned_data['description']
            scene = Scene(name=name.lower(), show=active_show, description=desc, creator=request.user)
            scene.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/overview/')
    else:
        form = SceneForm(initial={'creator':request.user,'show':active_show})

    return render_to_response('vfx_app/overview.html', {'active_show':active_show,'scenes':scenes,'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I suppose I could check the return type in the view function, but that seems kinda messy.

Comment: have you looked at class based views? this seems like a perfect scenario for them

Comment: try the reverse function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a decorator?

```
def requires_active_show(view):
    "The decorated view must take active show as a second argument."

    def wrapped(request, *args, **kw):
        show_pk = request.GET.get('s') or request.session.get('show_pk')
        if not show_pk:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/setup/')

        return view(request, Show.objects.get(pk=show_pk), *args, **kw)

    return wrapped

@requires_active_show
def overview(request, active_show):
    scenes = Scene.objects.filter(show=active_show).order_by('name')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SceneForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            desc = form.cleaned_data['description']
            scene = Scene.objects.create(
                         name=name.lower(),
                         show=active_show,
                         description=desc,
                         creator=request.user)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/overview/')
    else:
        form = SceneForm(initial={'creator': request.user, 'show': active_show})

    return render('vfx_app/overview.html', {
               'active_show': active_show,
               'scenes': scenes,
               'form': form
            })
```

Comment: You just ninja'd my code in about six different places. As well as answering my question, I've learned quite a few new tricks!

Comment: How does this work if you're using it on other views that have different arguments (besides needing "active_show")? Say, another view also needs the argument "scene_name".

Comment: Sorry, I fell asleep :) Edited my answer. It's a really simple change.